# Android Studio / Gradle Running NDK JNI Unit Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface

Is there a better way to run NDK Lib / JNI unit tests on device using Android Studio & Gradle?

Currently;

Build all NDK source and then use adb to push the built files to a tmp directory on device

e.g

```
adb push libs/armeabi/* /data/local/tmp; done
```

Run all of the tests on device

```
adb shell "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/tmp /data/local/tmp/run_all_unitTests"
```

Extract results

```
adb pull /data/local/tmp/test_results.xml
```

Comment: Even 5 years later we have no other way